# When developing for multiple devices how do I vary the UI for different devices e.g. phone and watch

Tags: bixby

When developing for multiple devices e.g. the phone and the watch, Bixby views normally work fine across devices but I am running into places where I need to vary the UI for different devices. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. Use the EL variable $can with if/then logic
2. Create a separate directory structure for the device

**#1 is great for small tweaks and is often all that is needed. The code would look like:**

```
result-view {
  ...
  render{
      if ($can.device == 'bixby-watch') {
    ....
    }
    else {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

**#2 is useful when there are large changes and simple if/then logic would be cumbersome.**

Here you create a device specific directory e.g. `/resources/base/views/result.view` for all devices except `/resources/bixby-watch/views/result.view` will override for the watch

[image]